# How to create Handler & Runnable Object in Android Inherited Activity Class

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an Inherited class which all of my Activities inherit.  In that Base/Parent Activity class I would like to create a Handler and Runnable Object that runs every 5 seconds in all Child Activities without having to add code in each Child Activity.  I have it working, where the Runnable Object is in the Inherited Activity but I can't seem to get around having to add code for the Handler in each Child Activity.

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    val handlerBaseActivity = Handler()
    val runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            Log.d("icepts","runnable from base...")
        }
    }
```

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity () {
    val handlerLocalActivity = Handler()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    handlerLocalActivity.postDelayed(runnable, 100)
    }

   override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        handlerBaseActivity.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    }
```

Anyone have any ideas that they'd be interested in sharing?  Thanks so much!

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend to use coroutines, this is the new and recommended way to handle concurrency in kotlin.

Comment: postDelayed(runnable, 100) call this on handlerBaseActivity in the BaseActivity onCreate

Comment: What is it that you want to do every 5 second in every activity? There might be a better way to do get the desired outcome...

Comment: Every 5 seconds I want to check to see if the Android App's data is sync'd to a server and change an icon in the ActionBar.  To Tim's comment, when I put the postDelayed in the BaseActivity, it does start but then I had issues with how to get it to stop - each activity started up a new Runnable Object.  If I put the removeCallBacks in the onPause of the BaseActivity then the runnable wouldn't run at all because the onPause of the BaseActivity gets executed before the Child Activity starts.  I'll look into CoRoutines so see if that can help - Any pointers for this application?

Comment: Don’t let each Activity sync data. Instead put data in a data store that does the syncing once and for all, and let Activities observe that data, e.g. using LiveData

Comment: Enselic, each activity isn't syncing data.  There is a background task doing the syncing.  I just want each activity to be able to update the ActionBar based on whether the sync is up to date or not.

Comment: Good! But why not make Activities subscribe to a "data up to date" state? Running code every 5 second will unnecessarily drain battery. Better if activities are notified of changes. LiveData would be a good subscription mechanism.

Comment: Enselic: Yes, I see your point.  I'll still need to the background task doing processing every 5 seconds, but I wouldn't need to have a Handler/Runnable executing every 5 seconds to update the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Activity's lifecycle** in the `BaseActivity` as well so that every child `Activity` does exactly the same work in their lifecycle callback. You need to `post` your `Runable` in the `onResume()` or `onCreate()` of the `BaseActivity` and remove it in `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`. Please see the example below,

**BaseActivity**

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    val handlerBaseActivity = Handler()
    val runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            Log.d("icepts","runnable from base...")
            // TODO perform your repetitive operation

            // call the handler again after 5 sec to perform above operation again
            handlerBaseActivity.postDelayed(this, 5000)
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        handlerBaseActivity.postDelayed(runnable, 100)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        handlerBaseActivity.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    }
}
```

After that, you do not have to call `postDelayed()` function manually in each `Activity` that inherits `BaseActivity`. So, to make `MainActivity` do the same operation that is written in `run()` function in `BaseActivity` you just simply inherit `BaseActivity`.

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity () {
    // no need to declare local handler

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        // No need to call postDelayed() of localHandler as it's already called in BaseActiviy 
    }

   // No need to remove callbacks in onPause() as it's already defined in BaseActivity
}
```

### Update

I want to clear your confusion of the following comment,

> If I put the removeCallBacks in the onPause of the BaseActivity then
>   the runnable wouldn't run at all because the onPause of the
>   BaseActivity gets executed before the Child Activity starts.

If you also have `BaseActivity` registered in the `AndroidMannifest` and it runs as an independent **Activity**, removing the runnable from it will not prevent any child from executing their runnable at all. Basically, all the childs will have their own instance of `runnable`s and `handler`s that will be tied to their own lifecycles.

Comment: This works. Really well.  I'm just not sure why because I would have guessed that the Runnable would start with the BaseActivity's onResume and stop with the onPause even before the Child Activity starts.  The BaseActivity is NOT listed in the Android Manifest.  It is just a Parent Class that has common code (like for the Navigation Drawer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Thread to perform this task. I am aware that in Kotlin you have Coroutines which are cheaper to instantiate and easier to manage, so you might want to go that path. Make sure you create your handler outside of this thread, that way when you perform UI changes you don't get errors, however, if you want to perform background tasks then don't use a handler at all. 
You can keep a reference to this thread so that you can pause it, by setting running to false and interrupting it, then setting it to null, for good measure, when you completely stop using it.

```
fun loop() {
 handler.post(runnable) 
 //or 
 runOnUIThread(runnable)
 //background task
}
Thread(Runnable{
  while(running){
   loop()
   try{
   Thread.sleep(1000 * 5)
   }catch(e: InterruptedException){
   //some weird stuff happened
   }
  } 
}).start()
```